# Cannot invoke "index" with an argument list of type'(of: ChecklistItem)'

Tags: ios, swift

I don't understand Xcode is returning this error when I have put item in an array, and set the variables for the ChecklistItem object. I have commented the line which is returning the error.

```
import UIKit

class ChecklistViewController: UITableViewController, AddItemViewControllerDelegate {

    var items: [ChecklistItem]

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        items = [ChecklistItem]()

        let row0item = ChecklistItem()
        row0item.text = "Walk the dog"
        row0item.checked = false
        items.append(row0item)

        let row1item = ChecklistItem()
        row1item.text = "Brush my teeth"
        row1item.checked = true
        items.append(row1item)

        let row2item = ChecklistItem()
        row2item.text = "Learn iOS development"
        row2item.checked = true
        items.append(row2item)

        let row3item = ChecklistItem()
        row3item.text = "Soccer practice"
        row3item.checked = false
        items.append(row3item)

        let row4item = ChecklistItem()
        row4item.text = "Eat ice cream"
        row4item.checked = true
        items.append(row4item)

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return items.count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChecklistItem", for: indexPath)

        let item = items[indexPath.row]

        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
        label.text = item.text

        configureText(for: cell, with: item)
        configureCheckmark(for: cell, with: item)

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            let item = items[indexPath.row]
            item.toggleChecked()
            item.checked = !item.checked

            configureCheckmark(for: cell, with: item)
        }
        tableView.deselectRow(at:indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        let indexPaths = [indexPath]
        tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }

    func configureCheckmark(for cell: UITableViewCell, with item: ChecklistItem) {

        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as! UILabel


        if item.checked {
            label.text = "√"
        } else {
            label.text = " "
        }
    }

    func configureText(for cell: UITableViewCell, with item: ChecklistItem) {

        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
        label.text = item.text

    }

    func addItemViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: AddItemViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func addItemViewController(_ controller: AddItemViewController, didFinishAdding item: ChecklistItem) {

        let newRowIndex = items.count
        items.append(item)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: newRowIndex, section: 0)
        let indexPaths = [indexPath]
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func addItemViewController(_ controller: AddItemViewController, didFinishEditing item: ChecklistItem) {

        if let index = items.index(of: item) { // Cannot invoke "index" with an argument list of type'(of: ChecklistItem)'
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
                configureText(for: cell, with: item)
            }
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {

            let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! AddItemViewController

            controller.delegate = self
        } else if segue.identifier == "EditItem" {

            let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let controller = navigationController.topViewController as! AddItemViewController

            controller.delegate = self

            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {
                controller.itemToEdit = items[indexPath.row]
            }


        }
    }



}
```

ChecklistItem.swift

import Foundation

```
class ChecklistItem {
    var text = ""
    var checked = false

    func toggleChecked() {
        checked = !checked
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to use indexOf the ChecklistItem must adopt Equatable protocol. Only by adopting this protocol the list can compare an item with other items to find the desired index

Answer (score 0):

You need to conform to Equatable protocol.. 
Any maybe google beforehand.

Comment: Why did you post a link to this question?

Comment: And instead of posting an answer that (tries to) links to a duplicate, vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: oops, yeah it should be the duplicate link. messed that one up. Thanks for marking though!

Comment: You should delete this answer.